# Cannot get DeviceId inside WebView using navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, expo, quaggajs

I am trying to get deviceid inside WebView using *navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices*. It works fine in android devices but in IOS devices its throws undefined error.